# Google signin playstore error

Tags: android, authentication, google-signin

I have google login in my android application. When i generated signed apk and install that APK, google login works well. But when i put that APK in playstore, google login not works.

I generated signed apk with my keystore. And i've already generate new fingerprint from my keystore for my application and put it in my credential and add new google-service.json to my application.

I'm not using firebase in my google login.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the SHA1 is different when plugged into the playstore, maybe download the APK of your in-store application and try to generate the Signing-certificate fingerprint.

Make sure the package name hasnt changed nor have your keys otherwise the login will be invalid,  read this: https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158849?hl=en#installedapplications&android

for some more information on it

Comment: so i need to download the signin certificate from console, and add it on credential ?

Comment: Give it a try, ensure that its the same values in production as the one you signed in the google console